# An error when I'm using DB with bookmark : exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, bookmarks

I'm working on WF, Im making a bookmark.
when I write the following I can drop this activity very well:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Validation;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;
using System.Windows;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using SimpleWebDesigner.ServiceReference1;

namespace SimpleWebDesigner.Bookmark_exmple
{
    class newBookmark: NativeActivity
    {

        Service1Client ser = new Service1Client();

        [RequiredArgument]
        public OutArgument<bool> Out_arg { get; set; }//=new OutArgument<string>(output);// { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            context.CreateBookmark("samename", new BookmarkCallback(OnBookmarkCallback));
        }

        protected override bool CanInduceIdle
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        void OnBookmarkCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object val)
        {

            bool approve;
            approve = (bool)ser.get_from_WF(1);
            Out_arg.Set(context, approve);            
        }
    }
}
```

like this page https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=F1FD3CCD21D87C68&id=F1FD3CCD21D87C68%21351&sc=documents

but when I read and wrote from DB via WCF, as the following code:

```
class newBookmark: NativeActivity
{
    Service1Client ser = new Service1Client();
    [RequiredArgument]
    public OutArgument<bool> Out_arg { get; set; }//=new OutArgument<string>(output);// { get; set; }

    void OnBookmarkCallback(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object val)
    {
        bool approve;
        string exp;
        approve = (bool)ser.get_from_WF(1);
        if (approve == true)
            exp = "momo";
        else
            exp = "yoyo";
        Out_arg.Set(context, exp);
}
```

when I want to drop this activity it didn't and shows me a pop-up window with the following error :exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Any help?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post the stack trace of your exception.  We can't guess what line its coming from.

Comment: it's not in runtime, when I drag it and drop it in the XMAL file, before I run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Given the minimal information you provide us all I can do is guess that the line

```
Service1Client ser = new Service1Client();
```

is causing your problems. For one there is no reason to create the Service1Client at design time. Additionally it suggest you are not disposing of it when it is no longer needed.

However as you are not displaying the complete activity I can't really say of there is code in a constructor or CacheMetadata() that is an additional reason for errors.

Comment: you are right, it's from Service1Client ser = new Service1Client(); but what can I replace it with?

Comment: I post the whole code of the activity and print screen for the xmal file. thank you

Comment: Only create the Service1Client when you need it in the OnBookmarkCallback() and make sure to call Close() or Abort() as needed when you are done with it. This way you can keep connections and sessions open far longer than needed. And as you noticed creating the service proxy in VS2010 fails, I assume because of missing config elements.

Comment: At design time there is no config information available that is why the Service1Client ctor is throwing an exception.